# Changing button value based on selected text (NOT Working in Firefox)

Tags: jquery, firefox

I'm building a WYSIWYG editor where I want a button value to change based on the selected text in contenteditable div. I have come up with the following jquery code which works fine in Chrome and Microsoft Edge, but NOT WORKING in Firefox.

```
function isHeadingButtonActive(e) {

        $('#btnShowHeadingControls').removeClass('activeButton');

        var e = event || window.event;
        var node = e.target;
        var buttontext = 'Paragraph';

        while(node.nodeName != 'DIV') {

            if (node.nodeName == 'H1') { 
                buttontext = 'Heading 1';
            } else
            if (node.nodeName == 'H2') { 
                buttontext = 'Heading 2';
            } else
            if (node.nodeName == 'H3') { 
                buttontext = 'Heading 3';
            } else
            if (node.nodeName == 'H4') { 
                buttontext = 'Heading 4';
            } else
            if (node.nodeName == 'H5') { 
                buttontext = 'Heading 5';
            } else
            if (node.nodeName == 'H6') { 
                buttontext = 'Heading 6';
            } 

            $('#btnShowHeadingControls').addClass('activeButton');
            $('#btnShowHeadingControls').val(buttontext);
            node = node.parentNode;
        }
    }
```

How can I make this work in Firefox?

When debugging with Firebug, I got this error message:

```
ReferenceError: event is not defined
```

Comment: `node.nodeName.toUpperCase()` perhaps? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeName sheds some light on this. Could Firefox be reading the document as XHTML instead of HTML? If not, what part specifically doesn't work in FF? Have you stepped through with a debugger?

Comment: I tried `node.nodeName.toUpperCase()`, but still doesn't work in Firefox

Comment: In that case, what about it isn't working in FF?

Comment: When debugging with Firebug, I get this error message: `ReferenceError: event is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery prop() here

```
$('#elem').prop("nodeName")
```

[example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/25bepvy4/1/)

Comment: Are you sure? I was testing before answer. And testing now still working.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to solve the problem.

The problem was that previously I was calling the function without passing the parameter `e` to the function as such:

```
isHeadingButtonActive();
```

To correct this, I just added the parameter `e` to the function as such:

```
isHeadingButtonActive(e);
```